# Routing error to WINS name without .local

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I'm having a weird issue on the network. all windows PCs behind the main router, XP, win 7 and win 8 are routing an adress incorrectly, to what looks like an external ip.

The machine, a netgear readynas 2, all the PCs are trying to reach does not have a FQDN, so there's no TLD in the address, just a WINS name without .local. The name it has is not the factory reset name, but a name given to it. If I add .local however, they find it.

The router is a Netgear FSV318g, also used for VPN and DNS. We also have a windows server 2003 (virtualised) acting as a WINS server.

Here's an ipconfig /all from one of the clients, in swedish unfortunately :)

```
IP-konfiguration för Windows

   Värddatornamn . . . . . . . . . . : Elevdator
   Primärt DNS-suffix. . . . . . . . :
   Nodtyp. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-routning aktiverat . . . . . . : Nej
   WINS-proxy aktiverat. . . . . . . : Nej
   Söklista för DNS-suffix . . . . . : sverige-halsan

Ethernet-anslutning Anslutning till lokalt nätverk:

   Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . : sverige-halsan
   Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : EC-A8-6B-A3-48-3F
   DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja
   Länklokal IPv6-adress . . . . . . : fe80::89a0:127b:6ed5:b019%11(Standard)
   IPv4-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.31(Standard)
   Nätmask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lånet erhölls . . . . . . . . . . : den 12 december 2013 08:20:32
   Lånet upphör. . . . . . . . . . . : den 14 december 2013 09:11:06
   Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
   DHCP-server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
   IAID för DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . : 200058987
   DUID för DHCPv6-klient. . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-78-FE-3D-EC-A8-6B-A3-48-3F

   DNS-servrar . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
   Primär WINS-server. . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.9
   NetBIOS över TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiverat

Tunnelanslutning: isatap.sverige-halsan:

   Tillstånd . . . . . . . . . . . . : Frånkopplad
   Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . :
   Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
   Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja

Tunnelanslutning: Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . :
   Beskrivning . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Fysisk adress . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiverat. . . . . . . . . . : Nej
   Autokonfiguration aktiverat . . . : Ja
   IPv6-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:285f:3d7f:3f57:ffe0(Stan
dard)
   Länklokal IPv6-adress . . . . . . : fe80::285f:3d7f:3f57:ffe0%13(Standard)
   Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS över TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Inaktiverat
```

I ran som nmap tests on the target IP 5.186.16.253, and it seems to be a router of some sort, no matter the last digits I get the same results:

```
Host is up (0.19s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
21/tcp  open  ftp
111/tcp open  rpcbind
Device type: WAP|specialized|media device|storage-misc|general purpose|broadband router
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linksys Linux 2.4.X|2.6.X (91%), Linux 2.4.X|2.6.X (91%), Crestron 2-Series (89%), Netgear embedded (89%), Western Digital embedded (89%), HP embedded (89%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linksys:linux:2.4 cpe:/o:linux:kernel:2.4 cpe:/o:linux:kernel:2.6.22 cpe:/o:crestron:2_series cpe:/o:linux:kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:linux:kernel:2.6.18
Aggressive OS guesses: OpenWrt White Russian 0.9 (Linux 2.4.30) (91%), OpenWrt 0.9 - 7.09 (Linux 2.4.30 - 2.4.34) (91%), OpenWrt Kamikaze 7.09 (Linux 2.6.22) (91%), Crestron XPanel control system (89%), Netgear DG834G WAP or Western Digital WD TV media player (89%), HP P2000 G3 NAS device (89%), Linux 2.4.18 (86%), OpenWrt Kamikaze 8.09 (Linux 2.4.35.4) (86%), OpenWrt Kamikaze 8.09 (Linux 2.6.25 - 2.6.26) (86%), Netgear WGR614v7 wireless broadband router (85%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
```

But when I connect through my phone to try an entirely different network I get different results, so I'm guessing it's not external after all.

I fixed the issue temporarily by editing the hosts file on the windows machines, but I'd like to find it what is causing the problem.

I'm a little stuck now and do not really know where to go from here and what tests to run. We have two IPSEC tunnels going out through this office. <strike>I disabled one of them, but can't disable the other right now, the people on the other side need it.</strike> I disabled both and the problem is still there.

Thankful for any tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Turnes out it was the WINS. When I disabled it in the router everything works fine.